# Can you return a variable from a Flow to the Aura Component that launched it?

Tags: visual-workflow, aura, lightning-flow-builder

When a Flow is launched from an Aura component as in the example below, I'd like a variable from the Flow to set an Attribute on the Aura Component that launched it. Is this possible?

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's API Name.
        flow.startFlow("myFlow");
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the lightning component attributes by using the lightning:flow onstatuschange action.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="flowOutput" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}"/>

    <div>
        {!v.flowOutput}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's API Name.
        flow.startFlow("myFlow");
    },
 
    handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {
        console.log(event.getParam("outputVariables"));
        if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
            let outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
            console.log(outputVariables);
            if (outputVariables && outputVariables.length > 0) {
                let outputVar = outputVariables.find(e => e.name === 'outputVar'); // You can search for the flow output variable
                if (outputVar) {
                    component.set("v.flowOutput", outputVar.value);
                }
            }
        }
    }})
```

You can find more information about this implementation in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_inputs_get.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The `onstatuschange` action returns following data:

1. activeStages
2. currentStage
3. flowTitle
4. helpText
5. guid
6. **outputVariables**
7. status

**outputVariables** We need to capture data of this param, it has all the variables which are available for Output.

The current values for the flow's output variables. It returns `Object[]`.

How to use:

Aura cmp file changes add the event handler for statuschange event:

```
<lightning:flow aura:id="flow" onstatuschange="{!c.statusChange}"/>
```

Aura Controller.js file changes add the handler method:

```
statusChange : function (cmp, event) {
    if (event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED") {
        const outputVariables = event.getParam('outputVariables');
        console.log('outputVariables: ', JSON.stringify(outputVariables));
    }
}
```

More information is available here in the official documentation [lightning:flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:flow/specification)